# List style none not applying + li border

Tags: html, css, list, nav

I am testing out vertical navigation and want to remove the bullets from my ul.
I have even tried applying !important in case there was an override. The bottom border on my li will also not apply. I have researched online but cannot find a solution.

Nothing within the "nav" id will apply except

```
#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/Saharalara/pen/WpPgpJ

Here is the html:

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>About Us</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="nav">
   <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">History</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Executive Team</a>
            <ul>
        <li><a href='#'>&raquo; CEO</a>
        <li><a href='#'>&raquo; CFO</a>
        <li><a href='#'>&raquo; COO</a>
        <li><a href='#'>&raquo; Other Minions</a>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href='#'>Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
    <h1>About Us</h1>
    <ul>
    <p><li><a href="#">Mission</a> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ultricies adipiscing lectus, pharetra mauris amet luctus, ac vitae pulvinar, aenean urna porttitor eu etiam eu non. Accumsan tortor sit ac integer. Ipsum occaecat ad ipsum vestibulum, pellentesque posuere, sit enim curabitur odio.</li>

       <li><a href="#">History</a> Ut at montesdui ullam orci, justo leo sem vitae sit quam, quis massa cras volutpat eget ac a.</li> 

       <li><a href="#">Executive team</a> Vitaeconvallis duis, dui adipiscing felis quam, laoreet nec non, lectus massa morbi et, amet nec in lacus urna.</li>

       <li><a href="#">Contact us</a> Proin enim venenatis diam nascetur odio, nullam dui nam mauris quisque dignissim, eleifend sed platea ut, risus temporibus ante eu, dui eros libero ultrices eget non. Iaculis mauris nulla phasellus vel, pede nunc et libero mauris ac, erat volutpat non netus sed risus sed, dignissim aenean sit curabitur.</li>
       </p>
       </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Css:

```
body {
    font: 12pt Verdana, Arial, Georgia, sans-serif;
}

#nav {
    width:150px;
    float:left;
    margin-top:12px;
    margin-right:18px;
}



#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
}


//making sure there are no extra padding or margins lying around to line up with ABOUT US content

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 12px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

//border for visual seperation

#nav li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffffff;
}



#nav li a:link, #nav li a:visited {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
    background-color: #628794;
    color: #ffffff;
}

//higlight when hover

#nav li a:hover, #nav li a:active {
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
    background-color: #6cac46;
    color: #000000;
}

#content {
    width:550px;
    float: left;
}

#content a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: try this one  https://jsfiddle.net/ak6vgcbu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code isn't the selectors, it's the comment.

If you're using raw CSS, you'll need to use block comments because inline comments will cause an error and then the rest of your CSS won't process. The reason that `text-decoration` works is because it occurs before your first inline comment.

Change

```
//making sure there are no extra padding or margins lying around to line up with ABOUT US content
```

to

```
/* making sure there are no extra padding or margins lying around to line up with ABOUT US content */
```

Comment: Thank you so much Christian. Cannot believe I overlooked that.